# VB.NET - search for directory and delete if it contains certain characters

Tags: vb.net

I have searched high and low and cannot find a way of doing this. I am writing a program that will run at logon and delete a directory within another directory. Our company has a software application that contains a directory that sometimes becomes corrupted. The issue is that the directory contains some static words and then is appended with a randomly generated set of characters. Thus, the need for a search for the static words and delete any directory that contains them. This is kicking my butt. Thanks for any help!

Edit:

My apologies for not adding some or all of the code that I've written thus far. I can delete the static directories, but not the dynamic ones. Again, I'm teaching myself and I'm sure there's better ways of doing what I need, but I don't know them. I'm also relatively certain that my code is messy and such. I would love some constructive criticism, but please don't bash me for trying. Please see below. Thanks!

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Public Sub Main()

'I'm wanting to see the user name output in the console
    Dim user As String
    user = Environment.UserName

    Console.Write(user)
  'new line
    Console.WriteLine()

    Dim path1 As String
    path1 = "\appdata\local\DIRECTORY\APPLICATIONNAME.exe_Url_ny2thmvtmqmw4jiqk1yuytwfbddruu02"

    Dim path2 As String
    path2 = "\appdata\local\DIRECTORY\APPLICATIONNAME.exe_Url_r3joylqll52q54guz0002pxu4swqous0"

    Dim fullpath As String
    fullpath = "C:\Users\" & user & path1

    Dim fullpath2 As String
    fullpath2 = "C:\Users\" & user & path2

    Dim toplevel As String
    toplevel = "\appdata\local\APPLICATIONNAME\"

    Dim toplevel1 As String
    toplevel1 = "C:\Users" & user & toplevel

    If Directory.Exists(fullpath) = True Then

        Directory.Delete(fullpath, True)

    ElseIf Directory.Exists(fullpath2) = True Then

        Directory.Delete(fullpath2, True)

    End If

'I would like to keep the window open until I work the kinks out
    Console.WriteLine("Finished. You may now close this window.")
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Good morning, RS! Thanks for the welcome! You're right-- I should have added my code. Essentially, I can delete statically named directories and have searched for code on how to search a directory name and delete any directories returned from said search, but I have not found anything that does this. When I've attempted to write something, I've gone blank on how to perform the action. I'd love to see how to do this and the logic behind it explained. I want to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need. I've included parameter names to make it more readable. You can strip them out if you prefer the more concise approach...

```
' Will find all directories under C:\Root\Folder\
' (including subdirectories) with a name that starts
' with "SearchString", then delete them and their contents
System.IO.
    Directory.
    GetDirectories(
        path:="C:\Root\Folder\",
        searchPattern:="SearchString*",
        searchOption:=System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).
    ToList().
    ForEach(Sub(x) System.IO.Directory.Delete(path:=x, recursive:=True))
```

That said, This is simply joining together two tasks:

- Finding a list of directories
- Deleting each one in turn

There are many tutorials and examples on the internet (and numerous questions on Stack Overflow) relating to these topics.

Edit: The concise version

```
Imports System.IO

Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Root\Folder\", "SearchString*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
    ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) Directory.Delete(x, True))
```

Comment: Thank you, Basic! Yeah, I've found loads of questions on how to delete directories, but nothing on how to find certain text in directory names and then delete the returns. I appreciate your wonderful and respectful answer. Usually, I find when I ask questions of folks, I get blasted for not being an expert. I'm trying to learn and search like crazy before asking for assistance.

Comment: No worries. I've edited to include the concise version too. Incidentally, you may want to have a skim through the help center if you're new, especially the [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section. It'll save you a little friction while you find you way around. Welcome to SO

Comment: Thanks again, Basic! I will absolutely check that section. Much appreciated, mate!

Comment: Basic, as an update, I used your code example to remedy my situation and it worked a charm. I appreciate your help! I had a few other kinks to work out and, after doing so, cleaned up my code and the app is alive and well. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. For future reference, "thanks" comments are generally discouraged as they tend to add clutter. Instead, consider upvoting or accepting our answers. This gives us reputation points and also lets others know this question has been answered. In particular, have a look at [this part of the asking questions help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You bet. I was going to do that, but cannot upvote anything due to my rep being low as I'm new. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

try using something like
this code below deletes every folder thats contains the pattern listed on
the string array.

```
Dim Words() As String = {"Word1","Word3","Word4",.."Wordn"}
For Each iPatternWord as String In Words
    For Each  iDir As System.IO.DirectoryInfo In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\",iPattern) 
       iDir.Delete(true);//===>Delete this folder.        
    Loop
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, @Basic and @MrAlex6204! I will try one or both of these! Y'all rock for answering so fast!